# Make mark color overlap highlight symbol at point

Tags: syntax-highlighting, colors, highlighting

I use [auto-highlight-symbol-mode package](https://github.com/mhayashi1120/auto-highlight-symbol-mode) to auto highlight symbol on point. I found it annoying when I mark a text because the symbol highlight overlaps on my marked text, so I don't see if I marked what I want to mark already.

I have no attachment to `auto-highlight-symbol-mode` package or anything else, I just looking for a way to have a auto highlight symbol functionality overlapped by text mark background color.

Any solution?

Comment: I updated the question. The package is called `auto-highlight-symbol-mode` https://github.com/mhayashi1120/auto-highlight-symbol-mode.

Comment: Sure, I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I ended up with is [symbol-overlay](https://github.com/wolray/symbol-overlay) package with `(setq symbol-overlay-idle-time 0.1)` which makes highlighting instant.